# I want to get the image URL from my document's field from firestore but it's throwing an error every time-

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
Container(
        decoration: homePageDecor,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 80,
            ),
            homePageText,
            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("Subscriptions")
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: ((context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  Map<String, dynamic> data =
                      snapshot.data!.docs as Map<String, dynamic>;
                  print(data);
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(data['URL'].toString()),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  );
                }
                return const Text("There is no data");
              }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

The Error i am getting: **type 'List<_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast**

I am trying to retrieve the documents fields from firestore. What should i use instead?

Comment: Hi does my posted answer solve your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Your provided code is casting `_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot` to `Map<String, dynamic>` which does not work because those cannot be casted to the provided type.

Instead if you see the type of  `snapshot.data.docs` which is `List<DocumentSnapshot>` then you can accumulate the `snapshot.data.docs` into `List<DocumentSnapshot>` so you can use it in following way:

```
final _constrcted = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("Subscriptions")
      .snapshots(); //declare this at the top of the build
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: _constrcted,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.data.!docs;
      return Column(
        children: [
          for (var document in documents)
            Container(
              child: Image(
                image: NetworkImage(document['URL'].toString()),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      );
    }
    return const Text("There is no data");
  },
),
```

It is always advisable to declare stream outside the streamBuilder as it will run only once in the life of build for more info on this check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74579960/streambuilder-did-not-display-the-data-from-firestore) and this [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes)

OR you can also use in the in the following way :

```
final _constrcted = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("Subscriptions")
      .snapshots(); //declare this at the top of the build
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: _constrcted,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Column(
                  children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                    return Image(
                      image: NetworkImage(document['URL'].toString()),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                );
              }
              return const Text("There is no data");
            },
          ),
```

If you want to use Map<> with typed firestore response you can use [Typing CollectionReference and DocumentReference](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#typing-collectionreference-and-documentreference)